# HTML onClick doesn't fire on rightclick

Tags: javascript, html, events, mouseevent

I've read that this is a problem in some browsers, but I'm still looking for a suitable solution.

My thoughts so far:

I could use the `onmousedown/onmouseup` event to distinguish between left and right mouse button. Since these events are called regardless of which button is pressed.

Problem with this is, that I only want to fire *onRightClick* event if the button was being pushed AND released above the same object. Not if the mouse button is pressed above the object and release else where (and vice versa).

Are there any workarounds which doesn't need complex code? like saving the clicked object in a global variable in `onmousedown`, and compare it to the object on which the `onmouseup` was fired. This seems unnecessary complex.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I'm using the JavaFX Webview, which doesn't seem to support the `oncontextmenu` event on SVG-Elements, which I need to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can attach 'contextmenu' event listener of the element you want. When you execute your code return false to prevent the standard context menu from appearing.

```
element.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Foo();
    return false;
}, false);
```

You must also return false in the function you are calling internally.

```
function Foo(){
    // some code 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I just edited my question. I already tried using the `oncontextmenu` event, which doesn't seem to be supported by the JavaFX Webview, which I'm using.

Comment: Did you use 'oncontextmenu' because its incorrect and the correct event that is thrown is 'contextmenu' also as I've researched, this event must be supported in the JavaFX WebView, please recheck :)

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` is a more explicit and arguably more readable alternative to returning `false` all around the place.

Comment: Adding the eventlistener with javascript is inpractical in my case, since the HTML Markup is dynamically generated by another application. JavaFXs webview is based on webkit. So try this fiddle with firefox, and you'll get my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/8yxt5fc1/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use mousedown event with `target` parameter with outerHTML attribute. Here's a demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/qjffdptq/

You can modify as per need. Hope this helps.